# Update entity when JOIN is used in the query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, telerik

I have this RadGrid with EF datasource which uses JOIN e.g.

```
var result = db.Programmes.Join(db.Faculties, prog => prog.FacultyID, fac => fac.ID, 
(prog, fac) => new {
                ID = prog.ID,
                FacultyID = prog.FacultyID,
                FacultyText = fac.FacultyName_mk,
                StudyLevelID = prog.StudyLevelID,
                Ects = prog.Ects
            }).ToList();
RadGrid1.DataSource = result;
```

So far so good. I have the data displayed correctly.

The problem comes when i want to insert a new item (programme) or to update an existing e.g.

```
protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
    // get the ID
    Int32 id = (Int32)item.GetDataKeyValue("ID");
    // get the current record
    var record = db.Programmes.Where(r => r.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    //update entity's information with what was entered in the RadGrid
    item.UpdateValues(record);
    db.SaveChanges();
    // close the edit form
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ClearEditItems();
}
```

this thing updates all columns except the FacultyID which should be taken from RadComboBox control;

```
<EditItemTemplate>  
    <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="cmbFacultyID" /> 
</EditItemTemplate>
```

I am bidning the combo from within ItemDataBound and it reads from Faculties entity.

How do i update Programmes table reading the FacultyID from this ComboBox?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns that i just needed to update the record right after i get from the query assigning the newly selected faculty e.g.

```
// get the current record
var record = db.Programmes.Where(r => r.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
// FIX
record.FacultyID = Convert.ToInt32(facultyid.SelectedValue);
// update entity's information with what was entered in the RadGrid
item.UpdateValues(record);
```

works fine now :)
Thank you